# Flow not accepting method called on ref

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I have a component that renders a `TextInput` and I've assigned a `ref` to that child component:

```js
return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          ref={ref => (this.textInput = ref)}
         // ...props
          }}
        />
        // ...other stuff
        )}
      </View>
    );
```

As instructed on the [Flow website](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-ref) I've set an instance property with type `?TextInput`:

```js
export class AutoFillMapSearch extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  textInput: ?TextInput;
  // ...
```

Flow accepts this as the type for the `ref`. However, when I write `this.textInput.blur();`, Flow complains:

```
Cannot call this.textInput.blur because property 'blur' is missing in null or undefined.
```

I understand that a `ref` is a maybe type so I sort of understand why this error is coming up, but I don't understand what to do to fix it.

(The app works great, it's just Flow that's complaining here.)

Comment: I think everything is fine here. Take a look at `ref functions`: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/refs/ Use logical operator for solution `this.textInput && this.textInput.blur()`

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` can be null at certain times in a component's lifecycle: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element

In order to protect against that, you need to check that the ref is not null before using it. To do that, you can use an `if` statement or `this.textInput && this.textInput.blur()` as @Marko Savic suggested in the comments.